# How do I insert values into BIT datatype?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

We have a checkbox on one of our forms.

If a user checks this box and clicks the Save button, we would like to have a value of 1 or True inserted into the table.

If however, the box is not checked, rather than inserting NULL, we would like to insert 0 or False.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: so... convert the checkbox value into a 1/0|true/false in code? what's so hard about that?

Comment: I agree with marc, you also don't specify where you are wanting to implement this, at code or database level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just checking for non null input:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (myBitField) VALUES (CASE
    WHEN @myCheckboxParameter IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1)
```

Comment: Marc B; I didn't think it was hard either but I forgot to mention that I did try code similar to that of Cube32 but it didn't work. I don't remember the exact error but I am going to try it again.

Thanks, Cube32

Comment: Sorry again @Cube32. I am trying to implement this at code (or app) level.

Comment: I must have been doing something really stupid. It seems to work now.